# How do I query a one to many relationship using the auto generated class I created using Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I want to query my database to receive an object in this order:

```
[
    {
        "categoryId": 1,
        "title": "First Category",
        "subject": ['Subjects Belonging to Category 1']
    }, 
    {
        "categoryId": 2,
        "title": "Second Category",
        "subject": ['Subjects Belonging to Category 2']
    }

]
```

from this class:

```
public partial class Category
    {
        public Category()
        {
            Subject = new HashSet<Subject>();
        }

        public int CategoryId { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }

        public ICollection<Subject> Subject { get; set; }
    }
```

I have tried getting all the categories iterating over them and setting subject but that was not working.

```
public ActionResult<IEnumerable<Category>> Get()
        {
            var categories = _testContext.Category.ToList();

            foreach(var category in categories)
            {
                var subjects = _testContext.Subject.Where(c => c.CategoryId == category.CategoryId).ToArray();
                category.Subject = new HashSet<Subject>(subjects);
            }

            return categories;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That code performs a new database query for each category, that's terrible for performance. Apart from that, you say you want a list of strings for subjects, not a list of subjects, so you need a DTO.

```
public class CategoryDTO
{
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public List<string> Subjects { get; set; }
}
```

Which you would use as:

```
public async Task<ActionResult<List<CategoryDTO>>> Get()
{
    return await _testContext.Category
        .AsNoTracking()
        .Select(cat => new CategoryDTO
        {
            CategoryId = cat.CategoryId,
            Title = cat.Title,
            Subjects = cat.Subject.Select(sub => sub.Title).ToList()
        })
        .ToListAsync();
}
```

Comment: I would suggest to append `AsNoTracking()` to the query.

Comment: @AlexanderSchmidt Why? Projection and in general queries which do not return entities are no tracking. Because there is nothing to track :)

Comment: I use this for explicity and to not forget it whenevet I will change it to eventually return entities. It‘s more about readability and stability and not technical.

Comment: @AlexanderSchmidt and @CamiloTerevinto Whenever you are projecting your query it will automatically be out of tracking. so you don't need to use `AsNoTracking()`  explicitly.

Comment: @TanvirArjel It's not needed, as Alexander mentioned, it's a matter of being explicit about what you want to do without having any drawback

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Got it!